# As you click on each item in a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have created a ListView, but don't know where to start to make clickable each element of the list.

My purpose would be to display in a different hubSection a lyrics of a song, based on the chosen one.

I created the:

```
SelectionChanged="TestiCanzone_SelectionChanged"
```

I have a method with this name. should I do there?

Comment: are you saying you want a checkbox?

Comment: No. I wanted that for each ListView item I opened a different text files

Answer (score 0):

No, use [ItemClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick.aspx) to know when the item is clicked. SelectionChanged event is fired when the items are selected or not.

Then in your handler, access `ClickedItem` property of [ItemClickEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs.aspx) arguments.

Comment: Should I do such a thing and then use the variable "Example"? `var Example = e.ClickedItem;`